# Expo - Run background tasks when the app is closed

Tags: android, ios, mobile, expo

Im creating an app that wants to run one task a day, i used
[Background Fetch](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/) alongside with [Task Manager](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/), and that works great when the app is in background. But i dont want to ask the user to leave the app running in background, since when you close the app, tasks stop running. Is there a way to run tasks when the app is closed? Or should i eject my app from expo to do that?.